# I am not able to redirect this page to about page, trying from last 2 hours?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import {FaBars} from 'react-icons/fa';
import {Nav, NavbarContainer, NavLinks, NavMenu, NavLogo, MobileIcon, NavItem, NavBtn, NavBtnLink} from './NavbarElements';
{/* Here is NavBar section*/}
const NavBar = ({toggle}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
         <NavbarContainer>
            <NavLogo to="/">Random</NavLogo>
            <MobileIcon  onClick={toggle}>
               <FaBars />
            </MobileIcon>
            <NavMenu>
               <NavItem>
                  {/*This is for logo*/}
                  <NavLinks to="generate" onClick={toggle}>Generate Password</NavLinks>
               </NavItem>

               <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="about" onClick={toggle}>About us</NavLinks>
               </NavItem>

               <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="strength" onClick={toggle}>check strength</NavLinks>
               </NavItem>
               <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="signup" onClick={toggle}>Sign Up</NavLinks>
               </NavItem>
            </NavMenu>
            <NavBtn><NavBtnLink to="/profile">View Profile</NavBtnLink></NavBtn>
         </NavbarContainer>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavBar
```

Here I have created different links in header section but when i am trying to redirect it, its not happening.
I read 20 articles in the last two hours but I am not able to redirect the about page.I am a beginner please help me in react.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Link as LinkS} from 'react-scroll';


export const Nav = styled.nav`
   background: black;
   height: 80px;
   margin-top: -80px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 1rem;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 10;

   @media screen and (max-width: 960px){
      transition: 0.8s all ease;
   }
`
export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   height: 80px;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0 24px;
   max-width: 1100px;
`

export const NavLogo = styled(Link)`
   color: #F90919;
   justify-self: flex-start;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   margin-left: 24px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;

   &.active{
      border-bottom: 3px solid #F90919;
   }
`;


export const NavMenu = styled.ul`
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   margin-right: -22px;

   @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
      display: none;
   }
`

export const NavItem = styled.li`
   height: 80px;
`

export const NavLinks = styled(LinkS)`
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 0 1rem;
   height: 100%;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
`;

export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;

   @media screen and (max-width: 760px){
      display: none;
   }
`

export const NavBtnLink = styled(Link)`
   border-radius: 50px;
   background: #F90919;
   white-space: nowrap;
   padding: 10px 22px;
   color: #010606;
   font-size: 16px;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   text-decoration: none;

   &:hover{
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      background: #fff;
      color: #010606;
   }
`
```

I have edited Nav, Naccontainer, NavItem, NavLogo, NavMenu, and NavLinks, Kindly check.

Comment: I think we need to see the code for NavItem and NavLinks (at least) in order to attempt helping you debug it.

Comment: I have added NavLinks and NavItems, Kindly check

Comment: add sample  in https://codesandbox.io/ for debugging is better

Comment: I'm afraid we still don't have enough information to go off... It looks like the intended behaviour is to scroll to a section on the page? If so, we need the code for the page, to be  able to determine that the sections are defined correctly, and we also need to know what the toggle function is doing, as that could also interfere with the expected behaviour. If you could put a sample up on codesandbox.io like @A.R.SEIF suggested, that would be ideal.